# Why is flux in field winding constant in DC shunt motor, but not series motor?

Tags: dc-motor, flux

As titled, why is the field winding constant in DC shunt motor, but not series motor?

Comment: In a shunt motor the field winding is connected directly across the supply voltage. In a series motor the field voltage is equal to the supply voltage minus the armature back emf, which is proportional to angular velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic flux, produced by the field winding in a DC shunt motor, would be constant on account of the constant current drawn by it from the supply, across which it would be connected.

[image]

In a series motor, with the field winding being in series with the armature, the magnetic flux, produced by the field winding, would vary as the field current / armature current (being one and the same) would with variation of the load.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A shunt motor's field winding is connected directly across the motor terminals hence, if you apply X volts to the motor you apply X volts to the armature and X volts to the field winding. If X is constant then the field current remains constant.

In a series connected motor, the field winding is in series with the armature hence, the current through the field is dependent on the current into the armature and that is dependent on the applied motor voltage and the mechanical load on the motor.